# Change CPU to GPU and Run OpenCL program and meet calling ambiguous prompt

Tags: c, opencl, gpu, cpu, distributed-computing

I can successfully compile and run my program with selecting CPU device. But when I change it to GPU, I meet tons of these errors:

```
<program source>:73:24: error: call to '__cl_pow' is ambiguous
    result = 700 - (x1+pow(x2,2)+x2*x3);

                       ^~~~~~~~~
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/lib/clang/3.2/include/cl_kernel.h:4662:27: note: expanded from macro 'pow'
    #define pow(__x, __y) __cl_pow(__x, __y)
```

Why could this happen and how should I do?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Most "is ambiguous" errors are because you are passing mixed argument types.

Most likely "x2" is float (correct?). "2" is getting interpreted as int. In other scenarios, people use "2.0" which is interpreted as double. Solution: Use "2.0f" to force float.

Comment: Thanks for your replay! I found that I choose the Iris GPU in my MAC which doesn't support double computation.